# Delphi WebAction - Request.ContentFields.Values['something'] size limit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Im having an issue with my web dll, compiled in XE5.

I use an AJAX POST via javascript to sumbit a base64 value for an image that was cropped.

The length is about 127 000 characters.

When logging the Request.ContentFields.Values['Base64Image'] in Delphi, the total length was reduced to 61 000, which then saves half an image.

Is there a size limit on Request.ContentFields.Text? If so, how do I overcome this? Can i save a base64 element directly from the HTML page?

Comment: Which webserver are you using? If it's IIS you must set the [`maxAllowedContentLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx) attribute high enough.

Comment: Im using IIS and have tried the above setting with no success. I got around the problem by breaking up the string, and using a web action, save the parts to text file, and after the last part is sent, i use the text file to create the image. Works great!

Comment: Great to hear you sorted out!