# Delphi - Max Size of TStrings.Text

Tags: string, delphi, request, size

I am having a similar problem to this question: [Delphi WebAction - Request.ContentFields.Values['something'] size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986553/delphi-webaction-request-contentfields-valuessomething-size-limit)

The dll I have has a way to create multiple entries via a POST request. In the specific instance where this is a problem the POST request size is approximately 250,000 characters. It seems, however, that Request.ContentFields.Text is truncating that value at around 65,527 characters, so the DLL is losing data when creating the entry. The question I referenced was never completely answered but the poster seems to have found a workaround.

I can't find any documentation on the maximum size of TStrings.Text.

I am still curious though, is there a max size of Request.ContentFields.Text, which is actually TStrings.Text?

Comment: Any restriction out of the ordinary (physical memory, address space) would be imposed by the web module itself, not TStrings.

Comment: Indeed. There is nothing to limit the size of `TStrings.Text`.

Comment: Isn't the maximum string length the 2 GB stack limit in 32 bit delphi?

Comment: @PieterB There is no 2GB stack limit. There is a 2GB address space limit. 4GB if the process is large address aware. And there is a limit imposed by the memory needing to be contiguous. That's another address space limit. The point is that the asker thinks that there's an issue with TStrings, but in reality the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the size limit of `TStrings.Text`, besides what restricts a normal `String` size.

That is corresponding to 2 GB.

Most likely the web interface is imposing those restrictions, as explained in the linked question.